# Callback with parameters and result

Tags: delphi, callback

I tried very long to find an answer for this, but didn't find anything. I am trying to pass a callback with data to a function.

This is my pseudocode:

```
TGetFreeNumber = function(data: Pointer): integer;


procedure TMyClass.AddToDatabase(cb: TGetFreeNumber{???});
var
  num: integer;
begin
  num := {{Invoke cb with parameters}};
  // INSERT INTO ... VALUES num ...
end;


procedure TMyClass.impl1(from, till: integer);

  function myCB(data: Pointer);
  begin
    result := 123;
  end;

begin
  AddToDatabase(@myCB(someData){???});
end;


procedure TMyClass.impl2(from, till: integer);

  function myCB(data: Pointer);
  begin
    result := 456;
  end;

begin
  AddToDatabase(@myCB(someData){???});
end;
```

I made some experiments with TMethod, but I don't find a fitting Invoke method like

```
procedure TMyClass.AddToDatabase(cb: TMethod);
var
  num: integer;
begin
  num := Invoke(cb.Code, cb.Data);
  // INSERT INTO ... VALUES num ...
end;
```

Comment: Passing nested functions is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, local functions are incompatible with procedural types like `TGetFreeNumber`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make two changes. Your `AddToDatabase` method needs to accept the callback's parameters as well as the callback method itself. This is needed so that it can pass them on to the callback when it invokes it.

```
procedure TMyClass.AddToDatabase(cb: TGetFreeNumber; data: Pointer);
var
  num: integer;
begin
  num := cb(data);
  // INSERT INTO ... VALUES num ...
end;
```

And you must also not use a nested function for your callback. It is against the language rules to take a reference to a nested function. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types#About_Procedural_Types) says:

> Nested procedures and functions (routines declared within other routines) cannot be used as procedural values.

So you should write this code like so:

```
function myCB(data: Pointer);
begin
  result := 456;
end;

procedure TMyClass.impl2(from, till: integer);
begin
  AddToDatabase(myCB, someData);
end;
```

Note also that I removed the use of `@` when passing the callback. Removing the `@` allows the compiler to check that that the callback meets the requirements. In your code it did not because it was a nested function. Your use of `@` yielded an untyped pointer and so evaded type checking.

Due to a historical quirk, the 32 bit Windows compiler will let you use a nested function as a procedural variable if you use the `@` operator to suppress type checking. Furthermore, calls to that procedural variable will work so long as the nested function does not refer to anything in its outer scope, or anything contained in `Self`. But this behaviour should not be relied upon in my opinion.

If you need your callback to have access to methods of an instance, make it a method type:

```
type
  TGetFreeNumber = function(data: Pointer): integer of object;
```

and pass the method of your class.

Or if you would rather use anonymous methods and variable capture, and your Delphi version supports them, then use a reference function:

```
type
  TGetFreeNumber = reference to function(data: Pointer): integer;
```

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I have following code now, which works http://pastebin.com/EmcK6n7G . But I would like to solve the problems you mentioned. 1) My Delphi 2007 doesn't know "reference to".  2) When I remove the "@", I get the error `E2094: Local procedure/function '..' assigned to procedure variable`, because it is an inner procedure. 3) Why shouldn't I use nested procedures? The problem is that this callback is only required for this single implementation. I took care not to access outer variables, since this leads to problems.

Comment: I think all of those issues are explained in the answer. Suppressing a valid error with this use of `@` is not really how I would go about programming. Others will tell you that it is OK to use nested functions, but I disagree. So do the rules of the language.

Answer (score 1):

It should be straightforward:

```
TGetFreeNumber = function(data: Pointer): integer;


procedure TMyClass.AddToDatabase(cb: TGetFreeNumber; Data: Pointer);
var
  num: integer;
begin
  num := cb(Data);
  // INSERT INTO ... VALUES num ...
end;
```